# How to make a function open from the main page in a new window with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, for-loop

I am trying to figure out how to make my HTML Buttons that open a JavaScript function when pressed open the functions in a new tab, so I can go back and click the new one.
This is for an assignment for college, and the professor does not want to have more than one page and it has to open the function (addition and multiplication tables separately).

I've been trying everything from making the variables global to nesting the variable into a main() variable and nothing works. It states that addition and multiplication functions are not defined.

I'm very new to JavaScript as this is my first semester, I apologize if this is very basic.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Math Tables</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function multiplicationTable(table){
    document.write("<table border='1' width='300' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>");
    document.write("<tr>");
    document.write("<td> * </td>");
    for (x = 1; x <=10; x++){
    document.write("<td>"+ x +"</td>");
    }
for (y = 1; y <= 10; y++) {
    document.write( "<tr>");
    document.write( "<td>" + y + "</td>");
for (z = 1; z <= 10; z++) {
    document.write("<td>" + (y * z) + "</td>");
    }
    document.write( "</tr>");
    }
    document.write( "</table>");
}

function additionTable(){
    document.write("<table border='1' width='300' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>");
    document.write("<tr>");
    document.write("<td> * </td>");
for (x = 1; x <=10; x++){
    document.write("<td>"+ x +"</td>");
}

for (y = 1; y <= 10; y++) {
    document.write( "<tr>");
    document.write( "<td>" + y + "</td>");
for (z = 1; z <= 10; z++) {
    document.write("<td>" + (y + z) + "</td>");

        }
    }   
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Math Tables</h1>

<p>
<input type="button" value="Addition Table" id="addition" onclick="additionTable();"/><br />
<input type="button" value="Multiplication Table" id="multiplication"onclick="multiplicationTable();" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "opening a function" and "opening a function in a new tab"? Functions don't "open", the execute. Also, you shouldn't use `document.write()` to create dynamic content on your page. That technique is 25+ years old and requires that your code execute linearly and it requires all kinds of string concatenations. Instead, you can dynamically create elements as needed with `document.createElement()` and for tables you can use the [Tables API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement).

Comment: And, if you are just trying to display the results of your functions in a new window, use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Comment: And, I'm sincerely sorry to say this, but if your paying someone to teach you to code with `type="text/javascript"`, `border='1' width='300' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'` `document.write()`, dynamically creating tables, and `window.open()`, and inline event attributes such as `onclick`, then you are learning from someone who is teaching how to write code for 1998. I'm not kidding. You should expect better from a college course and I'd tell the instructor that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Man you're telling me! lol, from the very beginning this class has been a **** show. From the Very beginning this professor doesn't provide any materials to learn or do any lectures, but he makes requirements such as that. I don't understand the nature of these online classes and it's obvious that no care or effort was put into them at all. $900 for a class that fails in teaching actual JavaScript is very disheartening.

Comment: That's just terrible, but unfortunately all too common. It's obvious your teacher doesn't know and understand HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and is just pulling "lessons" from the Internet for the students. I honestly would tell the instructor that what they are teaching you is useless, decades out of date, examples of how to do a specific thing, rather than a modern, standards-based curriculum on HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. After all, you are the customer!

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for actually learning more usable, modernized JavaScript? Would PluralSight, YouTube, or Udemy have something that could help me get a better understanding of the language? 

My midterms are next week and even though.. at the moment... I have 100% in the class, I feel like all my knowledge of the language I've learned so far is built on a house of cards. I would like to go back to basics and re-learn everything the right way.

Comment: Those places certainly will be better than what you've got. I would actually highly  recommend [The Mozilla Developer's Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). Mozilla are the stewards of the JavaScript language after Netscape went away and is considered the authoritative source on documentation. Look at the tutorials section of the link I included here. Stay as far away from W3 Schools as you can!